# Use EMF Forms for properties window

Tags: eclipse, emf, eclipse-emf, eclipse-gmf

Is there a way to replace the default/tabbed properties window with an EMF form?

I tried https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.papyrus.views.properties.doc/target/generated-eclipse-help/properties-view.html

However, 'Customize property view' option is not getting enabled even after I installed all the payrus additional components with Eclipse Oxygen.

Really appreciate your input.